# Using Entity Framework with the Template10s

Tags: c#, entity-framework, template10

Using Visual Studio 2015, after I create a new project using the Windows WPF Application Visual C# Template I can add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project through the project's Add New Item function by selecting it from the collection of data items displayed in the ADD New Item Window.

When I create a new project using the Windows Universal Template10 Blank or Hamburger Templates and try to add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project using the same procedure the ADO.NET Entity Data Model is not displayed for selection.

I need to develop an application that will access a SQL database and I thought it would be useful to use Entity Framework with one of the Template10s.

Is this possible or even desirable?

If the Template10 templates are designed for use with Entity Framework how can I add the Entity Framework (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) to the Template10 Blank Template?

Comment: template10 is a UI framework, it doesn't care what kind of data storage you use...

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.0.0` is the EF you are looking for... its part of the Asp.net Core release....  EF 6.5 will be very hard pressed to work it can be done but you would be better off with EFC

you can not use EDMX with this version is code-first only.

Another note... To access SQL Server you would need a service to do this